# Why are the returned minimum values displayed as zeros in DolphinDB?

Tags: select, minimum, dolphindb

- DolphinDB server version: 2.00.9.1 2023.02.20; linux64
- Operating environment: vscode dolphindb v2.0.921 / GUI

When I queried data, I found that the returned minimum values are all zeros, as shown in the following figure. Why is this happening?

[image]

The actual minimum values are as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI: Click **File** > **Preferences** to open a pop-up window, you can set the number of decimal places for floating-point number by the setting item **Default number of decimal places**.

VSCode: There is an option **Decimals:Actual** in the bottom bar. You can click it to set the number of decimal places, but it only supports 0~20 digits.

Note: There are precision limits for floating-point number. To compare two floating-point numbers, you should use the `eqFloat` function.